# Method of finite differences solutions help?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For homework we were given this sequence:

```
-2      8       27      85      260         ____        2365
```

And asked to find the number in the blank.
Well, I got the pattern, but it is the weekend, and I'm bored, so I decided I would put a random number in that blank and try to find a pattern in those numbers. I chose 2000.

```
2   8       27      85      260         2000        2365
```

I decided, to narrow it a bit, I would try to come up with a function where:

```
f(1)=2
f(2)=8
f(3)=27
f(4)=85
...
```

Up to all 7 terms. Researching a bit, I found the ["Method of finite differences"](https://web.archive.org/web/20171221011827/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/53223.html)
Plugging in my sequence I got:

```
2   8       27      85      260         2000        2365
    6     19    58      175       1740         365
       13     39    117      1565        1375
           26    78     1448        190
              52    1370      1258
                1318     112
                    1206
```

So it would be a polynomial of the 6th degree.
With that in mind, I came up with this:

```
f(1) = a(1^6) + 1b + c = 2
f(2) = a(2^6) + 2b + c = 8
f(3) = a(3^6) + 3b + c = 27
f(4) = a(4^6) + 4b + c = 85
f(5) = a(5^6) + 5b + c = 260
f(6) = a(6^6) + 6b + c = 2000
f(7) = a(7^6) + 7b + c = 2365
```

And therefore

```
a+b+c = 2
64a+2b+c = 8
729a+3b+c = 27
4096a+4b+c = 85
15625a+5b+c = 260
46656a+6b+c = 2000
117649a+7b+c = 2365
```

My question is, from here, how can I find solutions of a,b, and c for which this holds true?

Comment: If it is a polynomial with degree 6, why are you using $f(x)=ax^6+bx+c$? It should be $$f(x)=ax^6+bx^5+cx^4+dx^3+ex^2+fx+g$$ (forgive the poor lettering with $f$ being the function and a variable). This will give you 6 equations, 6 variables which is easily solvable e.g. using the gaussian ellimination.

Comment: You could also use Lagrange Interpolation to find a sixth degree fit.

Comment: @Hirshy I am not familiar with gaussian elimination. How would I use it to find the values of those variables?

Comment: Gaussian elimination gives you an easy tool to solve such systems of linear equations. Of course if you're not familiar with it, it won't help you. Maybe you know it by a different name? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) tells me that it is also known as "row reduction", and I know some more terms for that in german.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any formula. Start with:
$$\begin{matrix}
2&&8&&27&&85&&260\\
&6&&19&&58&&175\\
&&13&&39&&117
\end{matrix}$$
and observe  each term in the third line is thrice the previous term. Hence we may conjecture the continuation of this third line will be:
$$\dots\quad 117\quad 351\quad 1053$$
Let' s check this conjecture, computing back/upwards:
$$\begin{matrix}
2&&8&&27&&85&&260&&&&\color{red}{\mathbf{786}}&&&&\color{red}{2365}\\
&&&&&&&&&\searrow&&\nearrow&&\searrow&&\nearrow\\
&6&&19&&58&&175&&&526&&&&1579\\
&&&&&&&&&\nearrow &&\searrow&&\nearrow\\
&&13&&39&&117&&351&&&&1053
\end{matrix}$$
The conjecture is satisfied, and the missing term is $\;786$.

Answer (score 0):

The general polynomial of degree six is $an^6+bn^5+cn^4+dn^3+en^2+fn+g$.  But there is a simple formula:

$$2+6(n-1)+13{n-1\choose2}+26{n-1\choose3}+52{n-1\choose4}+1318{n-1\choose5}+1206{n-1\choose6}$$
This turns into a degree-six polynomial if you expand, for example ${n-1\choose2}=(n-1)(n-2)/2$

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for! How did you come up with this formula?

Comment: Second-year Numerical Methods.